# Can't find Developer Tools in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I recently read that [the Development Tools is available in LibreOffice since 7.2](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Macros), but I can't find it in my 7.5.9.2 (and then updated to 7.6.4.1) installation... It should be found under menu item for Calc `Tools -> Development Tools`.

I do find the option available in Writer, Impress, and Draw.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Are all the three access methods in [this article](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/dev_tools.html?DbPAR=BASIC) missing?

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the hint on 3 different methods. I think maybe the problem is that I had customized the Menu at some point and therefore, the menu item wasn't getting added upon upgrade to 7.2+. I was able to solve the problem with my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @harrymc 's indication about 3 different access methods.
The 1st method, via menu, is missing as to the reason I asked the question.
The 2nd method, via Tabbed Menu interface (Notebookbar), is also missing.
The 3rd method, via toolbar... I don't know which toolbar it would be listed under, but I was able to manually add it to the standard tool bar.

Turned out, it could be because I had previously customized the menu and/or the Notebook bar, so the **Development Tools** didn't get added in the upgrade to 7.2 (and above). So there are 2 branches to fix this problem... 1) Reset the Menu, but this would remove any customization to the menu list or 2) customize as described below.

1. `View -> Toolbars -> Customize`
2. In **Menus** tab (or **Toolbars** tab if you want to add to the toolbar).
   *NOTE: If you simply want to **reset** the menu*, press the **Reset** button and skip the rest of the steps.
3. In the **Search** box, type in *Development*, press TAB to execute search.
   *Development Tools* should appear in the **Available Commands** field.
4. On the right side, **Target** select *Standard*, and choose your insertion location.
5. Click the `->` arrow to add to the target toolbar.
6. Click **OK** to complete.

[image: Customize Toolbars]